# Loading values to two arrays using same randomindex, the arrays differ in values

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array **notes** having nine jpg's on it, and an array **items** nine label and nine url's on it.

this code have three boxes It selected 3 `items` randomly from an array items.

I have placed the randomly selected item's `label` inside 3 boxes, inside `<P>` tags, and `currosponding image on background from` array **items**

I have stored currosponding images of notes on randomIndex selection to array **notesselected** this is called to box002 img src

Class **box002** can be dragged and dropped to corresponding number in four boxes displayed. then blue digit and background in box dissappears.

**I have a working code now**

**My problem is that i want the box002 item should be same as the box digit, now drop is form left side box onwards**

**ie in USER POINT OF VIEW: if box002 digit is 2 the drop(leftmost box) should be blue 2 number with background url image2**

how to change my code to make this happen.

```js
var randomIndex;
var array2 = [];

    var items = [{
        label: '1',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image1'
      },
      {
        label: '2',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image2'
      },
      {
        label: '3',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image3'
      },
      {
        label: '4',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image4'
      },
      {
        label: '5',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image5'
      },
      {
        label: '6',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image6'
      },
      {
        label: '7',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image7'
      },
      {
        label: '8',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image8'
      },
      {
        label: '9',
        url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.jpg?text=image9'
      }
    ];

    var notes = ['https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=1',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=2',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=3',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=4',                                                                                                              'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=5',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=6',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=7',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=8',
      'https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=9'
    ];


    var tempimages = [];
    var notesselected = [];


    array2 = items.slice();

    var item;

    function rvalue() {

      ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
      boxtags = document.getElementsByClassName("box");


    for (var index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() *array2.length)

    item = array2[randomIndex];
    array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    try {
    ptags[index].style.visibility = "visible";
    ptags[index].textContent = item.label;
    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;

    tempimages.push({data: item,index: randomIndex
    });
    notesselected.push({data: notes[randomIndex],
    index: randomIndex});

    boxtags[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item.url + ')';
    } catch (err) {
    console.log('Exception');
    }

      }

    var tlen = tempimages.length;
    }


    function displayAllImages() {
    try {
    if (tempimages.length == 0) {
    rvalue();
    }

    var arr2 = notesselected;
    item = arr2.shift();

    image = document.getElementById('slide');
        //image.src = "images/"+item.data.url;
    image.src = item.data;
    image.dataset.itemIndex = item.index;
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    }
    };

    $(function() {
    displayAllImages();
    });

    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var el = document.getElementById(data);

    var x = document.getElementById("slide").dataset.itemIndex;
    var y = ev.target.dataset.itemIndex;


    if (x == y) {
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.backgroundImage = 'initial';
    ev.currentTarget.style.border = 'initial';
    var pParagraph = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;

    pParagraph.style.visibility = "hidden";

    item = this.item;
    var arrayvalue = item.dataindex;

    tempimages.splice(arrayvalue, 1);

    if (tempimages.length == 0)
    {
    rvalue();
    }
    displayAllImages();
      } 
    else {
    alert("WRONG PLACED");
    }
    }
```

```css
body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box {
      width: calc(10.3% - 4px);
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
      margin: -2px;
      border-radius: 0%;
      background-color: #99ffff;
    }

    .box {
      height: 15vh;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-size: contain;
    }

    .box002 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10.3vh;
      left: 40.98vw;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .box002 img {
      width: 14.0vw;
      height: 23.0vh;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    p {
      font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      color: #005ce6;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="containerr">
        <div class="pic" id="content">


    <div id="container">

    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="10">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="11">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="12">
       <p name="values"></p>
    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box002" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="2">
      <img src="" draggable="true" id="slide" border="rounded" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan it is hard to explain my problem if i reduce my code

Comment: @mplungjan   for a user side of view i will explain, thre round box at right can be dragged and droped to rectangrlboxes starting from left, on dropiing the rectangle box digit and bcakgground dissappear if digit on round box and rectangle box is same

Comment: My problem is that on from level 2(second time loading values to rectangle boxes), the digit appearing on round box does not match with the leftside boxes, even thought digits on roundbox and rectangle box are same it get deleted ondrop on second level

Comment: I only get Wrong Placed when I try

Comment: @mplungjan  try placing it on exactly top of blue digit

Comment: @mplungjan My problem is that on from level 2(second time loading values to rectangle boxes), the digit appearing on round box does not match with the leftside boxes, even thought digits on roundbox and rectangle box are NOT same it get deleted ondrop on second level

Comment: data-item-index on the square 6 is 4 and on th e round 6 it's 5 - is that your issue?

Comment: @mplungjan yes exactly

Comment: make randomIndex global in scope: `var randomIndex;
var array2 = [];`

Comment: @mplungjan I have made var randomIndex; var array2 = []; global in scope and edited my code snippet but no change

Comment: It worked for me

Comment: @mplungjan please view my edited code snippet

Comment: @mplungjan please post the working code snippet it would be a great help

Comment: Your code here works. I get a correct every time I run. I have to run from start because the new number is not in the leftover list

Comment: yes exactly how to correct it

Comment: Ah. Now we are getting to see what the question is. Before I got errors when the numbers were the same.

Comment: @mplungjan round box should be dropped to leftmostmox available(if error happen on that drop , the drop should be exactly on top of blue digit)

Comment: @mplungjan i want the eg: if round box digit is 3, the leftmost rectangularbox should be blue 3 digit with backgroundImage IMAGE3